# Add/remove child from supervisor children list at runtime in Elixir

Tags: elixir, actor, erlang-supervisor, actor-model

I know how to create a supervisor with an initial list of children.

```
defmodule TweetProcesser.DummySupervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link(opts) do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      Supervisor.child_spec({TweetProcesser.Worker, []}, id: :my_worker_1),
      Supervisor.child_spec({TweetProcesser.Worker, []}, id: :my_worker_2),
      Supervisor.child_spec({TweetProcesser.Worker, []}, id: :my_worker_3),
      Supervisor.child_spec({TweetProcesser.Worker, []}, id: :my_worker_4),
      Supervisor.child_spec({TweetProcesser.Worker, []}, id: :my_worker_5)
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: TweetProcesser.WorkerSupervisor]

    Supervisor.init(children, opts)
  end
end
```

But how can I make the functionality for adding new children or removing children from this list at runtime? In such way that other actors could call these functions while running in order to add or remove children.

Comment: with simple supervisor it is not possbile, take a look at: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DynamicSupervisor.html

Comment: Just FYI your IDs don't have to be atoms. You could, for example, use tuples to avoid creating a new atom for every worker. See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#child_spec/2-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach would be to use a DynamicSupervisor, followed by a one-off worker that gives the supervisor it's initial children.

Assuming this is the bare skeleton code for you processes

```
defmodule TweetProcesser.Worker do
  use GenServer

  def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], [])
  end

  def init(_) do
    {:ok, nil}
  end
end

defmodule StartInitialChildren do
  use Task

  def start_link([]) do
    Task.start_link(fn ->
      [:my_worker_1, :my_worker_2, :my_worker_3, :my_worker_4, :my_worker_5]
      |> Enum.each(fn id ->
        spec = %{id: id, start: {TweetProcesser.Worker, :start_link, []}}
        {:ok, _pid} = DynamicSupervisor.start_child(TweetProcesser.DummySupervisor, spec)
      end)
    end)
  end
end
```

You can then add this to your application children

```
defmodule MyApp.Application do
  # ...
  def start(_, _) do
    def children = [
      # ...
      {DynamicSupervisor, name: TweetProcesser.DummySupervisor, strategy: :one_for_one},
      StartInitialChildren
      # ...
    ]
  end
  #...
end
```

What happens is, your dynamic supervisor will start with no children.

Then the one off task will run, and start the 5 children you want it to start with.

After that, you can use the same line of code to start more children.

```
spec = %{id: some_id, start: {TweetProcesser.Worker, :start_link, []}}
DynamicSupervisor.start_child(TweetProcesser.DummySupervisor, spec)
```

Of course, you can make it nicer by defining helper functions, but to get the base functionality going, this should do the trick.

Also note that, as others here have said, you should probably avoid atoms as ids when you're starting processes dynamically, as they don't get cleaned up fully and there's an overall limit on the system.

Comment: Why use `StartInitialChildren` at all? Can't it be done simpler, without `StartInitialChildren`? By calling `DynamicSupervisor` directly from `Application`

Comment: For a basic example, sure. You can also take the logic there and put it in a function in the application module, to be called after the application starts.

Often, you're starting something that takes a while to start, though, so a one off "job" process is useful.